# How to get all the parents for an object?

Tags: force.com, relationships

Say I have a custom object, and I want to get the list of parents for it, is there a quick way to do it? I didn't see it in eclipse.  The only way I can think of is going to the object detail page and doing a search for lookup( or master(

Better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is a good development tool but it leaves something to be desired in the SOQL/describe/execute anonymous area...

In API: [Describe call](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) that would identify all fields and then for each check if they're lookups/master-details.

Eclipse IDE: Open "Salesforce.schema", painfully read through fields...

Real Force Explorer: it's all on one tab ;)
[image]

(I'm not related to RFE, it's at the moment somewhat outdated with API version 21, there are other tools... [but I'm a fan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527752/how-to-add-comments-in-soql)).

Comment: Please note there is no way to specify custom login URL , so if your org forces to a domain you will not be able to use it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a Mac, SoqlXplorer is an invaluable tool:

http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the schema builder to easily identify the parent objects of any object.

Answer (score 1):

[Schema Surfer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) does a great job of this. It is a free app you can install in your org. Great for finding out all sorts of details about your objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ajax Tools from the App Exchange (Free) and use it's Explorer, you'll get a screen that looks like this: [image: Apex Explorer Window] which shows parent/child relationships and helps you build queries from within your org on SF. You'll also get similar functionality if you want to work remotely using Force.com Explorer (Windows Only) which is also a freebie.

**Note:** I collapsed the fields under Line_Item__c to make the screen capture smaller .

I should add that one of the really handy features of this utility is that once an object is selected, if you just press the Describe button, it does a complete Schema query for you and returns the results in a table form that you can copy and paste into an excel spreadsheet. :)